# Prove a probability inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory

> Let $X,Y\sim\phi(x)$ be i.i.d. ($\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ denotes the PDF), show that 
>   $$P(|X+Y|\le1)\le2P(|X-Y|\le1).$$

My thoughts are standard, 
$$P(|X+Y|\le1)=\int_\Bbb R \rm dx\phi(x)\int_{-1-x}^{1-x}\rm dy\phi(y)=\int_\Bbb R \rm dx\phi(x)(\Phi(1-x)-\Phi(-1-x)),$$
in which $\Phi$ denotes CDF. And
$$P(|X-Y|\le1)=\int_\Bbb R \rm dx\phi(x)\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\rm dy\phi(y)=\int_\Bbb R \rm dx\phi(x)(\Phi(x-1)-\Phi(x+1)).$$
Then naturally,
$$2P(|X-Y|\le1)-P(|X+Y|\le1)=\int_\Bbb R\rm dx\phi(x)(2(\Phi(x+1)-\Phi(x-1))-\Phi(1-x)+\Phi(-1-x)). $$
Then I don't know what to do. Am I even on the right track? (I slightly doubt it because my professor labelled this problem as "hard" so I think it's kinda resistant to standard approaches. )

By the way, $2$ is said to be optimal here.

Comment: So, $\phi$ is any pdf or the pdf of the standard normal distribution?

Comment: If your interested I could try to do this via Mellin Transforms; which seems the logical technique for this type of problem.

Comment: @rrogers though I'm not familiar with Melin, I'll still be glad to see how it can be applied here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well I reached in my mind and pulled the wrong transform; I should have said Fourier, senior moment.  In any case I will work it out using that and Parseval's theorem.  From an overview I think that there is a trick in the statement; the "identical" in i.i.d.  seems to push the X-Y power spectrum to a maximum; or some such.  BTW: this type of problem is covered by the Fourier transfrom method.  For reference I use:M. D. Springer, The algebra of random variables (a great book) but this seems to cover the issue at hand https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/ma223/ranvaralg08.pdf

Comment: I just looked up the Springer book at Amazon: LOL-ROTF.  I never realized that I had a fortune inside of my collection of old used books :)  If you can't find it and are in the US I could loan it to you if needed; and if you promise to return it.  I had one guy who took off with a loaned book (:

Comment: @rrogers thanks for your suggestion. But I'm not in US :). And sorry about your lost book.

Comment: Would you object to my putting up a more obvious formulation?  And possibly a false conclusion ( I think) to have a hole poked in?

Comment: @rrogers never mind. Go right ahead. I'm glad to hear about any information that might be useful.

Comment: Done: I hope it helps.  I am a little insecure about the next step so I left it blank.  Feel free to edit, delete or move; since it's not a complete solution.  But I will try to clarify my subsequent reasoning and complete it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplification of the mathematics and needs to be finished.
First we stabilize the limits
$$ P\left(-1\leq\left(X+Y\right)\leq1\right)\leq2\cdot P\left(-1\leq\left(X-Y\right)\leq1\right)$$
$$ P\left(\left(-1-X\right)\leq Y\leq\left(1-X\right)\right)\leq2\cdot P\left(\left(-1-X\right)\leq-Y\leq\left(1-X\right)\right)
  $$
Uniform in limits but we can set the limits to conform with common CDF representation.
$$ P\left(\left(X+1\right)>-Y>\left(X-1\right)\right)\leq2\cdot P\left(\left(X+1\right)>Y>\left(X-1\right)\right)
  $$
So the CDF picture is simply three identical curves displaced by one in the independent variable: $$ \Phi\left(X+1\right)>\Phi\left(X\right)>\Phi\left(X-1\right)
  $$
Identifying X,Y as independent realizations of the same process we can say 
$$ \phi\left(X\right)=\phi\left(Y\right):\phi\left(Y\right)=\Phi'\left(X\right) $$